# MS Access use Combo-Box value as Query Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple form with two combo boxes.

cboProvince which contains a list of provinces [Alberta,Saskatchewan,Quebec]

cboClient which contains a vast list of clients. Each with a Province.

I am attempting to populate cboClient with clients from the province chosen in cboProvince.

My current VBA Code is contained in the "After Update" event in cboProvince and is as follows:

[image: Form Layout]

[image: Province Table]

[image: Clients Table]

```
Private Sub cboProvince_AfterUpdate()

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT tblCustomer.[Customer Name], tblCustomer.Province FROM tblCustomer WHERE Province = '" & cboProvince.Value & "'"

'Apply Row and requery

cboClient.RowSource = SQL

End Sub
```

I have double checked that my combo boxes are indeed named "cboProvince" and "cboClients"

Something to note as well is the "Province" Column in the "tbsCustomer" is a Combo-Box. I'm unsure if that makes a difference.

Unfortunately the cboClient combo-box does not auto-populate.

Comment: Try requerying. `Me.cboClient.Requery`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this has not solved the problem

Comment: Cascading combobox is proven technique and must requery dependent combobox. So something else is wrong with your setup and not enough info available to determine what. What is the RowSource of cboProvince? Are you using an autonumber PK/FK link or are you saving province name into record?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I have added more information above. This database is part of an assignment, so the data shouldn't need to be modified.

Comment: If Province is a combobox in tbsCustomer table that means it is a lookup field and most likely actual stored value is ProvinceCode not ProvinceName. So unless value of cboProvince is ProvinceCode, your cboClient will fail. I did ask for RowSource of cboProvince - is it SQL statement that includes ProvinceCode? I NEVER build lookups in table.

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem! Thank you so much. I was hitting my head against a wall since yesterday because of this!